# HTML - Image Not Load / Not Showing Aftrer Refresh Page

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, slider, slick.js

I tried to make a background slider and it working on localfile (Open Html file using browser). then i use xampp to tried on localhost. on the first load, all working just fine until i tried to refresh the page. The IMG slider change into grey color. the weird part is when i changed the page size on browser (chrome) using CTRL + or CTRL - , the image reappear. and worked just fine again. i think the problem in my browser. but i already tried another browser like firefox and edge even using brower on mobile phone, all of showed the same problem. so here's my code

html

```
<div id="bg-slider">
   <div>
      <div class="img-holder" style="background-image: url(images/slider1.jpg);"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="img-holder" style="background-image: url(images/slider2.jpg);"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
      <div class="img-holder" style="background-image: url(images/slider3.jpg);"></div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

javascript

```
if ($('#bg-slider').length && $.fn.slick) {
    
    $('#bg-slider').slick({
        arrows: false,
        autoplay: true,
        fade: true,
        dots: true,
        appendDots: $('.wrapper'),
        speed: 1000,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000
    });
    

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        $('.slick-slide .img-holder').height($(window).height());
    });

    $(window).on('resize', function() {
        $('.slick-slide .img-holder').height($(window).height());
    });
    

}
```

Comment: Please click edit then `[<>]` and produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I used :

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
     $('.slick-slide .img-holder').height($(window).height());
});
```

instead of :

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $('.slick-slide .img-holder').height($(window).height());
});
```

and it worked !